# How to resolve physical device for home LAN's 10.0.1.1?

Tags: networking, lan, dhcp, dhcp-server

**Main question**

How can I find out the physical device corresponding to 10.0.1.1 (in my home LAN)?

---

(I tried `dig`, which gave no physical device info, and `nslookup` and `host`, both of which failed.  BTW, as the last sentence suggests, I prefer Linux-oriented, or at least Unix-oriented, answers, but Windows or "non-Unix-Mac" would be OK too.)

---

(This is only a secondary curiosity.)

**Meta-question**

I'm trying to find out *where* is my DHCP server.  I know its IP is 10.0.1.1, but I want to know where it sits *physically*.

I thought that this would be an easy question to Google for, but I was very wrong!

And I can say the same thing for this post's question, which is basically a generalization of my original question

Hence this pathetic post.

So my meta-question is "what Google query strings should one use for these questions"?

*I'm completely baffled.*

Comment: Second part of your post (your Meta-question) should be a separate question. Do not mix questions here.

Comment: If this is your home network, then 10.0.1.1 is most likely your router and your dhcp server.  Have you tried browsing to it?  Physically, it will be connected to your internet service.  Any details you can provide about your network will help provide investigative suggestions.

Comment: @Paul: I zeroed in on 10.0.1.1 in the process of searching for my DHCP server, so I'm pretty sure that 10.0.1.1 is, as you say, my DHCP server.  Do DHCP servers always run on routers?  (I have only one router.)

Comment: Most domestic routers have DHCP enabled out of the box.  Unless you have specifically set up a dhcp server, you can be almost certain that your DHCP servera and your router are the same box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can offer you is something that may still only get you halfway there:

On your host machine (your own computer) you'll want to be on the same network as this device (10.0.1.2 through 10.0.1.254 will be safe bets). My assumption is that this is already configured for you and the dhcp server is giving out addresses in that pool.

Once all of that is confirmed you can do a few things:

-Ping that and then run an arp scan (arp -a in Windows and I'm pretty sure it's the same for Linux). You can find a corresponding MAC address to that IP and then look up what hardware corresponds with that MACs prefix (the first 6 alphanumeric characters).

-Install a tool like zenmap/nmap and run a full scan on that. You should get an idea of the hardware and OS running on it if it's not too locked down. It basically automates the above step and does a bit extra.

From there you've got a few options available to you. If you have a closet full of unique machines and you determine it's definitely not virtualized you can narrow it down with your eyes. If it's a machine you should have access to and discover RDP or SSH (or similar) is running you can try remoting in with known credentials and proceed from there.

Another thing worth mentioning is that you could use the trace route command (tracert (ip) n windows, traceroute (ip) in linux). This would give you an idea of what equipment may be in between you and the dhcp server, if any.

Happy hunting!

Answer (score 1):

Just "two cents" more:

e.g.
`mtr -nrwc1p --timeout 5  www.google.com`
is a nice replacement for traceroute (Hmm... don't know it if is available for windows)

`mtr --help` or `man mtr` for more info.

Comment: pathping may the equivalent to mtr on the Windows side of things